# What is the most efficient way to read an entire s3 bucket with lots of small objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with millions of small text files (an s3/cloudfront log bucket), I would like to read them all sequentially - is there a way to do that without millions of HTTP GET calls ?

Comment: Maybe use Athena? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to read them with my own code

Comment: Query the tables made available through Athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-athena-tables.html. I think you should be able to save the query results as a single CSV in S3 and then you can read that directly. You're going to need some abstraction over the logs bucket, whether it's Athena or EMRFS. And when I say Athena, I don't mean go into the AWS console and use Athena - I mean use the Athena APIs (from your own code).

Comment: Will you be reading the files repeatedly? If so, it would be worth running a process to combine the objects together so that it is easier/faster/cheaper on future runs.

Comment: @jarmod - I need, to feed all the raw data as-is to an in-house code, this is a constraint.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: yes, this is the process I'm thinking about, question is whether there is some other way to read the entire bucket rather than object-by-object. Such as maybe some AWS service that provides you with its contents on an EBS volume ?

Comment: There is no service to "provide S3 on EBS", but you can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command to copy files to EBS, or write your own code using the AWS SDKs. Alternatively, Amazon Athena can do a great job of reading data from many files and providing a single output, which can effectively combine all your files together. Then, your app would just need to read the one file.